# How to giving opacity to text using python pillow?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I want to give an opacity value to text using python pillow.

This is my code:

```py
    pos = (width, height)
    font = ImageFont.truetype(font_path, text_size)
    color.append(opacity)
    drawing.text(pos, text, fill=tuple(color), font=font)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example how you can add opacity to text:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont

image = Image.open("image.jpg").convert("RGBA")
txt_placeholder = Image.new('RGBA', image.size, (255,255,255,0))

font = ImageFont.truetype("example_font.ttf", 25)
draw_image = ImageDraw.Draw(txt)   

d.text((0, 0), "This text is transparent", fill=(0, 0, 0, 15), font=font) 
combined = Image.alpha_composite(image, txt)    

combined.save("image_with_text.jpg")
```